# Can all modular forms be written as Eta Quotients?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have been going through a couple of introductory courses in modular forms and am quite curious whether all modular forms can be written as eta quotients of the Dedekind eta function?

Comment: See here: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2014.12.002

Comment: You may also find [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1996-348-12/S0002-9947-96-01743-6/) relevant. Only 43 newforms can be expressed as eta quotients and LMFDB includes all of them.